# TimescaleDB very slow query after compression

Tags: postgresql, performance, timescaledb

I have got a hypertable (around 300 millions rows) with the following schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS candlesticks(
 open_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 close_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 open   DOUBLE PRECISION,
 high   DOUBLE PRECISION,
 low    DOUBLE PRECISION,
 close   DOUBLE PRECISION,
 volume      DOUBLE PRECISION,
 quote_volume      DOUBLE PRECISION,
 symbol VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
 exchange VARCHAR (256),
 PRIMARY KEY (symbol, open_time, exchange)
);
```

After compressing it with this query

```
ALTER TABLE candlesticks SET (
  timescaledb.compress,
  timescaledb.compress_segmentby = 'symbol, exchange'
);
```

The following query takes several minutes (it seems timescale decompress every chunk) whereas before it was only 1/2 seconds  :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (symbol) * FROM candlesticks 
ORDER BY symbol, open_time DESC;
```

If i add a time conditions like `open_time >= now() - INTERVAL '5 minutes'` it's better

I'am not really comfortable in Timescaledb / SQL performance so maybe it's normal and i shouldn't use compression for my table ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this looks to me like it could be a performance bug / limitation in our compression stuff in that compressed data may not currently support skipscan, which is the optimization around this type of distinct query. Can you file an issue on the timescaledb repo so we can prioritize / address? https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues

Comment: Actually, looks like there already is an issue; https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/issues/3070 can you add a note with your reproduction information there and an upvote on the issue?